# How Do i get the attribute inside a div element using selenium webdriver using python

Tags: python-2.7, selenium-webdriver

The html div tag is something like this

```
<div class="_1vC4OE _37U4_g">
₹
<!-- -->
15,190
</div>
```

And I want to extract the numerical figure 15,190.
The code which i wrote is something like this

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
url = 'required url'
driver.get(url)
elem = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div._37U4_g')
price = elem.get_attribute('value')
print('price of the item is:', price)
driver.close()
```

But it returns None. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
url = 'required url'
driver.get(url)
elem = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div._37U4_g')
price = elem.text
print('price of the item is:', price)
driver.close()
```

Your code will return nothing because there is no `attribute` called `value` from the HTML that you've posted.

Your code will result in correct output in case the HTML was like this

```
<div class="_1vC4OE _37U4_g" value = "₹15,190></div>
```